# Stop Font Awesome icon from stretching in Bootstrap form with validation

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm building a form with Bootstrap 3 and want to have a nice icon in the field using Font Awesome.

When I'm applying validation using bootstrapvalidator, the icon stretches to accommodate the error message.

Any idea how I can keep the icon inside the form field?

HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h2>Sign up</h2>
        </div>

        <form id="registrationForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Username</label>
                <div class="input-group col-sm-5">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#registrationForm').bootstrapValidator({
    // To use feedback icons, ensure that you use Bootstrap v3.1.0 or later
    feedbackIcons: {
        valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
        invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
        validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
    },
    fields: {
        username: {
            message: 'The username is not valid',
            validators: {
                notEmpty: {
                    message: 'The username is required and cannot be empty'
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
});
```

Example of the icon height being stretched:
[image]

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/waqe4wg2/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put "input-group" class in another div inside "col-sm-5" div.
Fixed code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="page-header">
                <h2>Sign up</h2>
            </div>

            <form id="registrationForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Username</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign up</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I was using ASP.NET MVC.
I solved it by moving the @Html.ValidationMessageFor part outside of 'input-group' div.

```
<div class="form-group">
     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
     <div class="col-sm-4 input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon">
         <span class="fa fa-user"></span></span>
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "user name" })
      </div>
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "col-sm-offset-2" })
</div>
```

HTH